# My mouse keeps on the mouse click

Tags: laptop, mouse, touchpad

Sometimes when I click something and release it, it will still keep the mouse button pressed. Like when I drag something and release it again, my laptop sometimes just keeps dragging. It wont release until I click again. I have tried without a USB mouse and I still have this problem.

Then I disabled the touchpad on my mouse and it still keeps on the mouse click. So it wouldn't be the hardware? It even does it randomly when I haven't even clicked. Like when I am just typing a long message, like this, it even randomly just clicks on something where the mouse is pointed at. What should I do?

Comment: Is it a wireless mouse?

Comment: no but why does that matter? It's not about the usb mouse...

Comment: It matters a lot; a wireless mouse could easily explain the problem. You should edit your question because you specifically said `I have tried without a usb mouse and I still have this problem.` which means that the problem happens with a USB mouse.

Comment: Can you provide the laptop model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a setting called "click lock" and make sure it is turned off. The exact location may vary depending on the make of your mouse, try under:
Control Panel > Mouse > Click (tab) > Click Lock

There is also an activation delay which would explain why it does not always happen

Comment: You are a genius my friend!

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that your USB mouse is not the culprit, check your touchpad driver. First, go to the laptop manufacturer's website to see if there is a more recent version. If it was recently updated, roll it back to the version that was installed on the laptop when it was new (or back to when the problem wasn't occurring).

Comment: But I disabled my tochpad as well, and it still happened

Comment: I'd try the driver update/rollback solution anyhow. If you disabled it with the touchpad manufacturer's driver/interface installed, that may have caused Windows to detect it as a new device and install the default Microsoft driver.

Answer (score 1):

Simply enable click-lock toggle and set the delay value to the maximum level. Furthermore try this [test](https://joltfly.com/mouse-drag-test/) and observe if it behaves abnormally while dragging the objects or not that will help a lot with proper fixation.
let me know if it glitches while dragging objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to boot from a [Linux disk](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and see if the problem remains. I'm assuming you are running Windows for this to work. If you find the problem goes away, then it's probably a driver or other software problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Win10: When unchecking the Click-lock toggle, instead of disabling it, it stayed enabled but set the delay to zero. In order to work around, I had to enable it and set delay to maximum. This is still not ideal, but it is sufficient for most situations.